# React: How to handle multiple reusable inputs and change exactly the one we change inside an object

Tags: reactjs

I've got a problem with handling multiple reusable input components. What I want to do is get a single input and change its value inside an object which is inside a state. All inputs are the same and only difference as an attribute would be an id, but I'm not really sure how could I use it. My state is just an array of objects, I want to grab an object which I'm already editing and change an input value inside of it. An object I want to edit has three values: id, title and description in it. If there is any similiar question asked please let me know, I couldn't find any.

```
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState<any>([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Step 1",
      description: "Test1",
    },
  ]);
```

```
export const RecipeDetailsStep = ({
  id,
  title,
  description,
  steps,
  setSteps,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <StepDescription
          id={id}
          placeholder="Description"
          value={description ? description : ""}
          onChange={(e) => {
            // const stepToChange = steps.find((el: any) => el.id === id);
            // stepToChange.description = e.target.value;
            // setSteps([ ...steps, stepToChange);
          }}
        />
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interesed I found a solution. I don't know it's the best one but it surely works. Function would look like this:

```
  const handleInputChange = (id: number, property: string, value: string) => {
    setState((prevData: any) =>
      prevData.map((item: any) =>
        item.id === id ? { ...item, [property]: value } : item
      )
    );
  };
```